# Как в replit + java импортировать класс из другой папки

Tags: java, core

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в replit + java импортировать класс из другой папки?

Перепробовал всё

```
import LibrarianNew.Classes.*
import Classes.*
import LibrarianNew.Classes.Book
import Classes.Book
```

Ничего не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Импортировать надо пакет, а не класс

Comment: Я же так и делаю. Пакет называется Clases Вот один из неработающих вариантов import Classes.*

Comment: У вас имена классов совпадают, возможно отсюда конфлит имён. Тогда вам надо путь к пакету прописывать не с импорта, а непосредственно у ссылки на объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java импорт классов осуществляется на пути classpath. А также, если класс находится в пакете, то он должен лежать в соответствующей папке с названием пакета. В настройках надо искать где выставлять папку с исходниками и куда будут выкладываться откомпилированные классы. Если класс не находится в пакете, то он должен быть в корневой папке с остальными классами, интерфейсами.